# Filter and remove arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a filter method that check if `result` doesn't contain value from `this.state.filter` it should be delete.

My problem is method doesn't remove wrong `result`. It makes `null`

```
filter(){
    const {fetchData} = this.state;
  return  fetchData.map((result, index) => (
      (result[3] == this.state.filter) ?
      result :  null //there is my problem
    ))
  }
```

screens from `console.log`

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Maw.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFhSx.png)

Comment: `fetchData` is an array ?

Comment: Yep, it is an array which contains other arrays

Comment: You should probably give an example of your `fetchData` input, and how the function is called. And if `result[3]` is an array then it won't be equal to another array, you can check if the array contains the same values though, or the same values in the same order. Take a look at "[How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `map` you must be using `Array.prototype.filter` to remove elements from array:

```
filter() {
  const { fetchData } = this.state;
  return fetchData.filter( (subarray) => (
    subarray[3] === this.state.filter
  ));
}
```